# GetClassName[] in c++ returns SWT_Window0 on mousehover on IE

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, visual-c++

I am writing a code to get the class name of internet explorer when mouse hovers over IE. I have used WindowFromPoint() to get the current window below the cursor and have passed the retrieved window in the GetClassName(). When i print the class name i get the value as SWT_Window0 instaed of INTERNET EXPLORER_SERVER. Please tell me the solution to solve this issue

Comment: A quick search seems to indicate that the `SWT_Window0` thing seems to be related to the Eclipse [Standard Widget Toolkit](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/). Are you sure you have the right coordinates for `WindowFromPoint`? Are the coordinates you have relative to some window, or the sc5reen?

Comment: I have a button on a dialog. when the button is clicked the corrdinates are collected. So before clicking on the button i maximize the IE and bring the dialog over the IE. so when i click on button and hover the mouse over IE i get the coordinates

Comment: `WindowFromPoint` performs a [deep search](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101230-00/?p=11873), but it looks like you want a shallow search.

Comment: I have further improved the code by using ShowWindow() function which restores the IE window and activates it but still i am getting the class name as SWT_window0 when i hover the mouse in IE region

Comment: SWT is a Java toolkit, not surprising to find back in a browser.  It ought to have the WS_CHILD style turned on.  Calling GetAncestor() with GA_ROOT to get the root window might get you somewhere.  Depends, browsers do things differently.  Use the Spy++ utility to have a look-see at the window hierarchy.